# Partial download for Drive documents

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to use [partial download](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#partial_download) for all files from Google Drive.

For files that have 'downloadUrl' attribute - partial download works great.
But partial download doesn't work for 'exportLinks'.

```
range = "bytes=0-100"
result = client.execute!(:uri => url, :headers => {"Range" => range})
result.body.size
 => 3960
```

How can I use partial download for Google Documents(Documents, Spreadsheets, Presentations, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

There is an argument that a partial download of an export link makes no sense. The media content contained in an export download is generated dynamically by a Google file conversion process. There is no guarantee that the exported data will always be the same, eg. Google could easily tweak its toHtml conversion, or add additional meta data within a PDF.

What is your use case - perhaps there is a different approach? It shouldn't be too difficult to create a proxy on AppEngine which downloads the exported content and then offers a partial download.

Comment: I just want to use streaming download for all drive files.(Read data in chunks and write it directly in local file). In order to prevent memory issues. My application using this lib(http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/)